# Not able to not match substring and match string

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regular-language

I am quite new to regular expressions and I have been strugling with finding the correct one for my need an it is the following:
I need to get if the string starts with a "n" or a "p" and for that I have ^(n|p).
Next up any three of combinations can happen and for that I have (fcombination|scombination|tcombination), after that it's where I problem start to rise.
I need to match if "hvt" happens after previous conditions, but not if it's just "hv" other than "hv" any substring should be match.

Can any of the experts help?

Regards

Comment: Please show some actual before and after data and what you would expect to match and not match.

Comment: `^[np](fcombination|scombination|tcombination)(?!.*\bhv\b).*\bhvt\b`? Or, if there cannot be `hv` and the end of string after the initial conditions, `(?!.*hv$).*hvt` instead of `(?!.*\bhv\b).*\bhvt\b`?

Comment: nfcombinationhv can not be a match, nfcombinationhvt should be a match, and finally nfcombination(other single character)hvt(other characters) should be a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're after, the regex `^[np][fst]combination(?!hv(?!t)).*` would match

```
nfcombinationhvt  //match
pscombinationhvt  //match
ntcombinationhvt  //match
nfcombinationdrums  //match
pscombinationguitar  //match
ntcombinationkicker  //match
nfcombinationhvxxx  //no match
pscombinationhvzz  //no match
ntcombinationhva  //no match
nfcombinationhv  //no match
pscombinationhv  //no match
ntcombinationhv  //no match
```

Comment: nfcombinationhvxxx  //no match
pscombinationhvzz  //no match
ntcombinationhva  //nomatch Everything else is correct

Comment: Hi again, let's, my pattern has changed slightly instead of [fst]combination I need something like (combination|combinationalfa) while maintaing the behavior at of the pattern, an example ncombinationalfa->match,ncombinationalfahv->not match,ncombinationalfahvt->match, I have ^[np](combination|combinationalfa)(?!hv(?!t)).* and I does not work, from what I understood is due how the engine processes the string